# How to extract "label" and "help_text" data from Django Rest Framework serializer?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have defined Item model in models.py exactly like below.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=3000)
    seller_user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    buyer_user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    listing_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    creation_tsz = models.DateTimeField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    shipping_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    currency_code = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=5)
    product_data = JSONField(null=True)
    personalization = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

I have also defined my ItemSerializer with part below.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    transaction_id = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length=25)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=3000)
    seller_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, validators=[validate_positive])
    buyer_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, validators=[validate_positive])
    listing_id = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, validators=[validate_positive])
    creation_tsz = serializers.DateTimeField()
    price = serializers.DecimalField(label='Price', max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, validators=[validate_positive])
    shipping_cost = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, validators=[validate_positive])
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    currency_code = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=5)
    product_data = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    personalization = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000, allow_null=True)

    def update(self, item:Item, validated_data):
        #Validating whether
        if 'product_data' in validated_data:
            schema_obj = item.item_type.schema
            try:
                print(validated_data)
                jsonschema.validate(
                    json.loads(validated_data['product_data']),
                    schema=schema_obj)
            except Exception as e:
                raise ValidationError({'product_data':[f'Schema for product data is not valid. {str(e)}']})


        for key in validated_data:
            setattr(item, key, validated_data[key])
        item.save()
        return item

    def validate_product_data(self, value):
        """
        Validate whether property is json parsable
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            cur_obj = json.loads(value)
            return value
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValidationError("This field should be in format of JSON.")
```

In this problem I want frontend application(a VueJS app) to automatically show up error message dialog based on serializers label and ValidationError messages. Thus I have decided to use custom exception handler by changing settings.py like below.

```
....
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ....
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'OrderManagement.utils.exception_handler',
    ....
}
....
```

And finally exception handler function was like below.

```
def exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = views.exception_handler(exc, context)
    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.ValidationError):
        response.data['validation_meta'] = {key: {'nicename': NICE_NAME_DICT.get(key, key)} for key in exc.detail}
        ser = context['view'].get_serializer_class()()
    if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.NotAuthenticated)) and response:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    if response:
        response.data['errcode']=response.status_code
    return response
```

I was able to get serializer into "ser" variable but I was not able to get all fields with "label" properties.

After gathering label and/or help_text information my goal is to produce rest response like below for my VueJS app.

```
    {
        "price":[
            "Price should be a number"
            ],
        "metadata":{
            "price":{
                "label":"Price",
                "help_text":""
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to get it by creating object of related serializer and use "get_fields()" method. I have also tried to gather field specific data on class properties.

How can I extract "label" properties of all fields from 'ser' variable(which is context serializer)? I guess "help_text" property would be gathered with similar methodology.

Comment: What specifically do you want for the `label` property? The name of the field (eg `transaction_id` or `title`)? Or something else? Adding some examples of your expected output will help to get an answer

Comment: For example there is a label property for price field in ItemSerializer and its value is "Price". In order to generate ValidationError response with an additional metadata field, I should gather label information within exception_handler, so I can generate a Json response like below. 

  '{
   "price":[
    "Price should be a number"
    ],
   "metadata":{
    "price":{
     "label":"Price",
     "help_text":""
    }
   }
  }'

Answer (score 4):

Code below worked so well. Firstly there should be instantiated an object from ItemSerializer and fields dictionary has all fields with label and help_text data.

```
def exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = views.exception_handler(exc, context)
    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.ValidationError):
        ser = context['view'].get_serializer_class()
        ser_obj = ser()
        response.data['validation_meta'] = {}
        for key in exc.detail:
            if key in ser_obj.fields:
                response.data['validation_meta'][key] = {'label': ser_obj.fields[key].label, 'help_text': ser_obj.fields[key].help_text}

    if isinstance(exc, (exceptions.NotAuthenticated)) and response:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    if response:
        response.data['errcode']=response.status_code
    return response
```